# Power Query for all folder names listed in Column A of excel SS

Tags: vba, powerquery

I have a list of folder names in sheet 1 column A of my spreadsheet. I want to power query for each folder listed in A to retrieve all the files and load into a table. I want a separate table for each folder so I do not want to do a power query of the parent folder bc 1- it takes too long and 2- I want separate tables. How do I turn the query below so it will do it for each FOLDERNAME listed in column A.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="FOLDERNAME", Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Folder.Files(""L:\FOLDERNAME\"")" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source"
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""FOLDERNAME"";Extended Properties=""""" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [FOLDERNAME]")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
          .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Are you sure it takes longer to do one large query then many smaller queries for the same data? Otherwise I would have suggested making one large table then just filtering it when use

Comment: Maybe not in the end, but I would be able to do it in pieces this way. I did the whole folder originally and after 8 hours and reading 25,000 records it crashed, so nothing was ever loaded. Doing it for each subfolder I would at least have those load if it crashed and I could split the list up so it is not looping through the entire list at once.

There are a total of 182 folders and who knows how many subfolder and files with in those but there is a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to do it, I'd probably write a VBA that had a loop that pasted each consecutive folder name from Column A into a named range cell. Within the loop, have the VBA refresh the powerquery that references the named range, copy the PQ results output as a table onto a new sheet, then increment the loop

So decided to do it

Sheet **Master** has column A with list of directories, and a named range **Directory**

[image]

I create powerquery named **Query1** with a reference that range name.  Here I am pulling in the entire contents of the .xlsx files in that directory

```
let FolderName = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Directory"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
 Source = Folder.Files(FolderName),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".xlsx")),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Name", "Content"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "GetFileData", each Excel.Workbook([Content],true)),
#"Expanded GetFileData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "GetFileData", {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Name"}, {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Sheet"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded GetFileData",{"Content", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind"}),
List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"Removed Columns"[Data], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Data", List,List)
in  #"Expanded Data"
```

Close and Load the results as a table on a new tab. Name that new sheet **Output**

Create a VBA

```
Sub LoopMacro()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, bRfresh As Boolean
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To N
        Range("Directory").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master").Cells(i, "A")
     
    With ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - Query1").OLEDBConnection
        bRfresh = .BackgroundQuery
        .BackgroundQuery = False
        .Refresh
        .BackgroundQuery = bRfresh

    End With

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

  Next i

End Sub
```

What it is supposed to do is (a) loop through all values in Column 1 of tab Master (b) copy that to the named range (c) refresh the powerquery (d) copy the output tab to a new tab (d) loop and repeat

It does work .. with one caveat .. it seems to be creating duplicates of the query for each time through the loop. Someone smarter than me can attempt to address that. The rest works